# Writing code that applies to multiple check boxes in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I am trying to write some code for a VBA userform that has about 100 checkboxes.  I was wondering if there is a way that I could have one piece of code that applies to any checkbox or if I have to write 100 seperate functions for checkbox1_click, checkbox2_click, checkbox3_click, etc.

Thanks for any help in advance :)

edit: I realized that it would help to explain exactly what I am trying to do.  There will be 100 check boxes and whenever one is clicked I would like to do this:

Call CheckBoxClicked("checkboxname")

Comment: as you question stands the answer is you can have: one *piece* of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in a class moduled named **clsCheckBoxHandler**

```
Public WithEvents chk As MSForms.CheckBox

Private Sub chk_Click()
    MsgBox chk.Caption & " Clicked!"
End Sub
```

then in the Userform

```
Dim chkCollection As Collection


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim cCont As Control
Dim chkH As clsCheckBoxHandler

    Set chkCollection = New Collection

    For Each cCont In Me.Controls

        If TypeName(cCont) = "CheckBox" Then

            Set chkH = New clsCheckBoxHandler
            Set chkH.chk = cCont
            chkCollection.Add chkH

        End If

    Next cCont

End Sub
```

this is just a simple handler for checkboxes that has a click event but can be extended to cover multiple controls and events.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.  If its not too much to ask, could you show me how I would write this program so that when a checkbox is clicked, it runs a sub passing the checkbox name as a string.  Basically I want every time a checkbox clicked it to do Call CheckBoxClicked("checkboxname").

Comment: I actually figured it out. Thanks so much :)